# Package with an environment-based sectioning mechanism?

Tags: sectioning, environments

Is there any package for LaTeX that performs sectioning using environments, where doing something like

```
\begin{section}[Section Title]    
\begin{section}[Subsection Title]  
\begin{section}[Subsubsection Title]  
\begin{section}[Subsubsubsection Title]    
\end{section}  
\end{section}  
\end{section}  
\end{section}
```

does the obvious thing (please infer from the stuff in the `[]`'s!)?

Comment: Just out of interest, may I ask what is your need?

Comment: Well, let's not confuse needs with wants!

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12001/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-beginsection-endsection-in-latex.

Comment: @Raphink — the general idea with markup like this is that you can move chunks of documents without having to adjust the section levels manually (e.g., all `\section` -> `\subsection`, and so on).

Comment: The recent release of the [`coseoul` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/coseoul) may be of interest. Although it does not provide sectioning environments, a relative sectioning style through levels is implemented: `\levelup{...}`, `\leveldown{...}`, `\levelstay{...}` and others.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in an answer to the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12001/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-beginsection-endsection-in-latex) @lockstep linked above, I have some non-maintained code to attempt this here: http://github.com/wspr/newsec. (Run the .dtx through LaTeX to get the .sty file and the documentation.)

If you do find this useful or otherwise have comments, let me know and I'll consider putting it on CTAN. (Depending how long it takes to tidy up.)