# Change the spacing around select paragraphs

Tags: spacing, sections-paragraphs

How would I make only **specified** paragraphs have a little extra space above and/or below them compared to the default setting (which seems to be no--or very little--extra space between paragraphs)?  An entire newline is too much space (i.e., `\\*` is too much space since it adds an entire blank line).

Answer (score 3):

I would define a macro and manually insert it above/below the specific paragraphs you want adjusted in this way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcommand{\extraparskip}{\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\extraparskip

\lipsum[3]

\extraparskip

\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

The advantage of such an approach is that you can adjust the macro in the preamble and obtain a globally adjusted effect. I've used `\bigskip` above, however, you might be interested in something more subtle like `\medskip` or `\smallskip`.

You could also define an environment and encompass the specific paragraph(s) within it. However, this [groups the paragraph contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12001/5764) (making changes within local), which could affect other things.