# Unnumbered chapter/paragraph with \begin{chapter}

Tags: sectioning

I know that I can use

```
\chapter*{Title}
```

in order to have a chapter with no number. I was wondering if it is possible to do the same using the following?

```
\begin{chapter}{Title}
% Chapter content
\end{chapter}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but **not** recommended! You can use any LaTeX (!) command `\foo` with `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}`, since the `\endfoo` command is implicitly definef if `\newcommand{\foo}{...}` is used.

Comment: Thanks. Why is not recommended? I'm asking this because I prefer the \begin{} \end{} since it makes my latex code cleaner.

Comment: Because `chapter` is no environment ;-)

Comment: `\begin{chapter}*{Title}`

Comment: thanks a lot to both DavidCarlisle and SoundsOfSilence :D

Comment: Don't use `\begin{chapter}{Title}`, the correct way is `\chapter{Title}`. Using an environment adds nothing

Comment: Related: [Is it a bad idea to use `\begin{section}` … `\end{section}` in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12001/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd recommend it but you can do

```
\begin{chapter}*{Title}
```